# php mysql select box

Tags: php, mysql

I have a selection box and I wish to loop over to add to the database. It looks right to me but it will not enter into the database.

```
<select name="countylist" style="height:300px;" class="multiple" multiple="multiple" id="box2View">
      <option value="11">Beer Gardens</option><option value="10">Historic Bars</option>           
      <option value="8">Live Music</option><option value="1">Night Clubs</option>
      <option value="4">Pubs Serving Food</option><option value="6">Sports Bars</option>      
 </select>
```

SQL:

```
foreach($_POST["countylist[]"] as $s) {  
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cat_pubs (pub_id, cat_id) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),". $s . ")");

  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `foreach($_POST["countylist"])`

Comment: no doesn't work either, thanks anyway, although I am sure it is an array

Comment: Change the name from 'countylist' to 'countylist[]' in the HTML

Comment: no sorry adding name="countylist[]" not doing it either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to adjust the name of the select to include the array marker `[]` like so:

```
<select name="countylist[]"...
```

Then in PHP remove the array marker like so:

```
foreach($_POST["countylist"] as...
```

What is very important is that in PHP you check the input is actually one of the allowed values and not something the user input themselves maliciously. For selects it may be easiest to hold an array of allowed values and then check against this:

```
if(!in_array($s, $allowed_counties)) { /*false input, do not save in db*/}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the name of the select tag to `countylist[]` so that PHP knows it represents an array:

```
<select name="countylist[]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with that `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

- Have you done an insert before which you are now trying to refer to?

In that case, store the value in a variable because it will be overwritten after your first (new) insert.

- Are you trying to have the insert take the next autoincrement?

Then just don't name the column in your insert, or put NULL in the value:

```
INSERT INTO cat_pubs (cat_id)   VALUES(". $s . ")");
```

PS: You **will** get hacked by MySQL Injection if you just insert data from POST straight into your DB by building SQL from strings like that. Escape the string, or use a prepared statement...

Comment: I am just testing for now, thanks though for the advice I will be changing after testing

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers, you need to tell the POST that the value is an array with `name="countylist[]"` else your only get the last selected value in php.

Also if your doing multiple inserts it is always faster to build a single query for insert compared to iterating over the result and inserting on each iteration.

Your also selecting the database on each iteration which is wrong:

```
<?php 
//connect
mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
//select your db
mysql_select_db('database');

//is posted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //build query for a single insert
    $query = 'INSERT INTO cat_pubs (pub_id, cat_id) VALUES ';
    foreach($_POST["countylist"] as $s) {
        $query .='("","'.mysql_real_escape_string($s).'"),';
    }
    //trim the last ,
    $query = rtrim($query,',');
}

//do query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<form method="POST" action="">
  <!-- tell POST that countylist is an array --> 
  <select name="countylist[]" style="height:300px;" class="multiple" multiple="multiple" id="box2View">
      <option value="11">Beer Gardens</option>
      <option value="10">Historic Bars</option>           
      <option value="8">Live Music</option>
      <option value="1">Night Clubs</option>
      <option value="4">Pubs Serving Food</option>
      <option value="6">Sports Bars</option>      
 </select>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

thats ok for an example, I have one remark:

use mysql_real_escape() like

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cat_pubs (pub_id, cat_id) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),". mysql_real_escape_string($s) . ")");
```